# How to handle BluetoothGattCallback overwrite method onCharacteristicChanged() notification

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am trying to connect my android application with `BLE`. When an App connects with `BLE`,  i want to read the characteristic data.

But in my case, all the characteristic response come in `onCharacteristicChanged()` method.

How I can handle multiple characteristic notifications at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any read response in onCharacteristicChanged. You will only get read response in onCharacteristicRead.

What comes in onCharacteristicChanged are notifications and indications. I'm not sure what you mean with multiple notifications "at the same time". If the peripheral sends multiple notifications in sequence, the onCharacteristicChanged will be called the same number of time in sequence.